# Залипают очереди в RabbitMQ (Yii2)

Tags: php, yii2, rabbitmq

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется на борту Yii2 (2.0.15.1) и связка с RabbitMQ для реализации межсервисного взаимодействия.

Проблема следующая - в определенный момент сообщения перестают обрабатываться и просто висят в очереди

Помогает только перезагрузка консьюмера (в нашем случаем - перезагружаем docker контейнер)

Очередь работает посредством yii2 команды (в фоне)

Сталкивался ли кто-либо с таким и если сталкивались, то как решали.

P.S. извиняюсь за, возможно, глупый вопрос

Comment: Начните с просмотров лога консьюмера как минимум. Не перегружайте  контейнер, а зайдите в него и посмотрите состояние консьюмера в тот момент когда сообщения перестали обрабатываться. Возможно что консьюмер падает и не поднимается (вы реализовывали автоподъем после падения , через Supervisor например ? )

Comment: @zalex есть идея в php делать `exit -1;` ибо как оказалось, порой очереди залипают из-за потери коннекта с БД (в данном случае - postgresql)
Однако бывает что и коннект есть с БД, но и логов нет, как будто уходят в никуда